# Push New Row to Table on Ng-Click with Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object, push

how would one go about pushing a new row to a table with an ng-click? 
This is what I have currently. The information is in an array.

My array looks like this.

```
$scope.workflows = [{
                Id: 1,
                Name: "Workflow Page 1",
                Description: "Describe Workflow",
                Steps: [{
                    Id: 1,
                    Name: "name me",
                    Description: "describe me",
                    Action: "do something",
                    Obj: "whats the goal",
                    AdditionalInfo: "anything else",
                }, {
                    Id: 2,
                    Name: "name me",
                    Description: "describe me",
                    Action: "do something",
                    Obj: "whats the goal",
                    AdditionalInfo: "anything else",
                },
                ]},

          }, ];
```

This is what I want to add to my array and how I'm using scope to try to add it.

```
$scope.addStep = function(newStep) {
   $scope.newStep = [{
          Id: 0,
          Name: "Step on THIS!",
          Description: "I dare ya!",
          Action: "STOMP!",
          Obj: "A Rock",
          AdditionalInfo: "I am bleeding...",
        }]

   $scope.workflows.push(newStep);
     alert("test :" + "Its GON WORK");

 };
```

Then in the HTML I use an ng-click to active the newStep function, hoping that it creates a new row in my table.

```
<div class="text" ng-click="addStep(newStep)"> + Click to Add a New Step</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: use `console.log` or angular's $log to debug instead of `alert` for debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing your ng-click to: ng-click="addStep()"

then in your viewmodel:

```
    $scope.addStep = function() {
        //all the stuff you have currently

        $scope.workflows.push($scope.newStep); // line that changed
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Below method will add a new step in first workflow's `Steps`. You can pass workflow's `$index` in `addStep` method and replace the `0` by it to be able to add a new step in `$index th` workflow.

```
$scope.addStep = function() {
    $scope.newStep = {
      Id: 0,
      Name: "Step on THIS!",
      Description: "I dare ya!",
      Action: "STOMP!",
      Obj: "A Rock",
      AdditionalInfo: "I am bleeding...",
    };

    $scope.workflows[0].Steps.push($scope.newStep); // It will add a new step ($scope.newStep) in first workflow's Steps
};

<div class="text" ng-click="addStep()"> + Click to Add a New Step</div>
```